# connecting to a Windows computer as a named user, via WAN

Tags: windows, networking, domain

Some server software (named **Software**) is running on a Windows PC (**pc1**). On the same LAN, client software is connecting to this server software. A parameter in the config file says `ServerName=pc1\software`.

I believe that 'software' here is a service username and the client software tries to authenticate as this user 'software' on the 'pc1' computer. This works. What also works is using the server's ip: `ServerName=192.168.1.12\software`.

Since these are of course local hostnames and IPs, the client-server connectivity no longer works when the client connects from outside the LAN.

I thought it should be as easy as:

- configuring the router to allow incoming connections
- replacing the server IP in the config file with the WAN-facing IP

However, even though I've tried both port forwarding and placing the server in the router's DMZ, connections now time out.

Is anything else needed for Windows to accept log-ins with a username from the WAN? Does this style of logging in require a particular set of ports to be open? Should I configure the Windows firewall in addition to the router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am trying to go through this step by step.

- Almost any (sane) server software has a adress scope to listen to. If the server is configured to answer to requests only from it's own subnet (which is the default in many cases), it will not answer to requests from WAN. As long as you don't hack around with a two-sided-NAT implementation on your firewall (which I would not recommend).
- The ConnectionString you typed looks like a SQL connection string. If the connection target is a [SQL] database, check it's listeners configuration.
- Be ***very very very*** careful, when exposing hosts to the internet. *Especially* when you are unsure about the used protocols, transport encryption, authentication, used services or the data itself. That's what VPNs were invented for.

> Is anything else needed for Windows to accept log-ins with a username from the WAN?

As the ConnectionString you described is nothing used by windows but by a special application, the answer would be no. If you want to knwo what certain windows service would need to work over wan, you'd have to ask about it. There are a *lot* of services a Windows box can provice and no 'fits all' answer, sorry.

> Does this style of logging in require a particular set of ports to be open?

That depends on th e service you want to connect to. It would be very helpful here, to know what you are trying to achive.

Connecting to unknown services through unknown ports with unknown service configuration in unknown setup is not that easy.

> Should I configure the Windows firewall in addition to the router?

You will always have to make is possible for your packets to reach their destination. *Every* firewall  between the source (source-pc) and the destination (pc1\service) has to be configured to let a connection happen.

Comment: Thanks. This touches on a number of interesting points I was unaware of: that server software listens to a certain subnet. I think this is where it fails. In the end I solved the problem with Hamachi to quickly create a VPN, but for the future I will still read up on the subnet thing.